# Python matlibplot format_coord

Tags: python, plot, lambda

[image]

I am having issue with the X and Y co-ordinates being hidden in the plot.
Can anyone help how to fix this.
The values of the `spectrogam X`, `Y` and `Z` are maybe shown on the corner but is hidden.
How do I align the `format_coord` to more central.

I tried to format it with

```
pylab.format_coord = lambda x, y, z: 'x={:g}, y={:g}, z={:g}'.format(x, y, z)
```

but with no results.
the align function is missing here to align the lambda to more central or align left.